# Putty can only SSH into Linux VM from Windows 10 host only after I ping windows 10 host from inside the VM

Tags: ssh, windows

Weird scenario here, I have a RHEL VirtualBox running on my Windows 10 machine and I discovered that if I try to SSH from PuTTY into the VM, I get a `Fatal Error: Connection Refused`. However, if I ping my Host IP from within the Box, I can then SSH from my Host into the box just fine. This strikes me as odd and I am guessing that this is more of a "Windows" problem since it appears that my host cannot find the IP unless I cache it by pinging it. Whatever be the reason I would like to understand it if possible.

Edit : Please let me know if the question is inappropriate for this site, I will move it to stackoverflow if it is.

Comment: perfectly fine here, have you look at `sshd` log (e.g.  any error in `/var/log/*.log` ) ? `dmesg` ?

Comment: The question might be off topic here yes, if the issue turns out to be on the Windows side (which is indeed possible), but it is most certainly off topic on Stack Overflow as it has nothing to do with programming. Your best bet, if it turns out to be off topic here, is [su].